# Something be to try to do something

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[China Move to Cut Duties on U.S. Imports Lifts Auto Stocks](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-12-11/china-is-said-to-move-on-u-s-car-tariff-cut-trump-tweeted-about)

“Last week, events seemed to conspire to throw the truce into disarray, but the underlying incentives of both sides at the moment **are to try to** maintain that truce,” said Freya Beamish, chief Asia economist at Pantheon Macroeconomics Ltd.

[be to do something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-to-do-something)

There are 4 meanings of "be to do something". I think it's

> used to talk about arrangements for the future

here.

I can't understand how "incentives" can be arranged to **"try"** to do something?
I think only people (or such kind of things) can "try". I also can't understand an "arranged" "try".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main, copular meaning of "are" is used here. You can even flip the sentence, although some changes are needed to make it grammatical:

> ...to try to maintain that truce is the underlying incentive of both sides at the moment.

It's pretty common to see verbs/verb phrases (either in gerund or *to*-infinitive form) used with "to be". (Actually, from a grammatical perspective both sides of the verb can be a *to*-infinitive, like in this famous quote: ["To be is to do."](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/09/16/do-be-do/))